# Insert into access db successfully executenonquery but data in table not shown

Tags: ms-access, c#-4.0

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                            "Data Source=" + path + 
                                            "Persist Security Info=True");

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Customer ( CustFName, CustLName, Address, Gender, Email, Phone, Organization) values ('" + fname_AC.Text + "','" + lname_AC.Text + "','" + address_AC.Text + "','" + gen_AC.Text +"','" + email_AC.Text + "','" + ph_AC.Text + "','" + org_AC.Text + "')";
conn.Open();
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Message.ToString();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the value of the variable `path`? Could you step in this code with a debugger and check what is the value of the variable?

Comment: Are you sure you're refreshing your table to show the latest changes?

Comment: How do you show data in the table? You might have to refresh the table as @TomCollins suggested.

Comment: Actually the database which was being updated was located in bin folder and the database I was checking is in project folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually the database which was being updated was located in bin folder and the database I was checking is in project folder